# Install nmon on alpine

Tags: alpine-linux

How do I install nmon on alpine?

```
# apk add nmon
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  nmon (no such package):
    required by: world[nmon]
```

I read through the below links but being a newbie, couldn't figure out where the repo is.

Source - http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php

Request to add nmon to alpine - https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/6961

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nmon` package is currently available only in alpine-edge testing repo as can be seen here:
[Alpine packages - edge/testing](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nmon&branch=edge&repo=testing)

Important information about edge: [AlpineWiki-Edge](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge)
Also note the warning:

> Warning: "edge" is under constant development so be careful using it
> in production. It is possible that bugs in "edge" could cause data
> loss or could break your system